# Get the key by calling the key and value tru input in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this nested dict and i want to get the key (class A or B) if i call the key and values inside of key (john and 19) tru input how can i do that? Plss help

```
people = {   
    "class A" : {"camille": 19, "krinny": 19, "eunisce": 18},
    "class B" : {"john" : 19, "roi" : 19}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a super-efficient data structure for this sort of access. You need to search through the dictionaries to find the values you are looking for. Here's an example that returns the first found. If there's a possibility that the name may appear in more than one class, you could return a list instead.

```
people = {   
    "class A" : {"camille": 19, "krinny": 19, "eunisce": 18},
    "class B" : {"john" : 19, "roi" : 19}
}


def findClass(name, people):
    '''
    Returns the first class with the name 
    or None if not found
    '''
    return next((k for k, v in people.items() if name in v), None)

    
findClass("john", people)
#class B

findClass("krinny", people)
# 'class A'

findClass("joe", people)
# None
```

Comment: class1 = {
 "class A" : {"teacher" : "simbahan", "Room" : 201 , "Schedule" : "MWF" },
 "class B" : {"teacher" : "krinny", "Room" : 202 , "Schedule" : "TTh" }
 } I have this new dict but what i want if i enter the name of teacher (value) like simbahan or krinny the output is class A or B how can i do that am new here in python can you help me

Answer (score 0):

```
people = {   
    "class A" : {"camille": 19, "krinny": 19, "eunisce": 18},
    "class B" : {"john" : 19, "roi" : 19}
}
```

there are several ways;

(1) access by keys

```
people["class B"]["john"] #will give you 19
```

(2) iterate on items

```
for key1, item1 in people.items():
    # key1 is class A or class B
    # item1 are dictionaries for class A and class B
    print(key1, item1)
    for key2, item2 in item1.items(): # then iterate on the item1
        print(key2, item2)
```

will print as below:

```
    class A {'camille': 19, 'krinny': 19, 'eunisce': 18}
    camille 19
    krinny 19
    eunisce 18
    class B {'john': 19, 'roi': 19}
    john 19
    roi 19
```